# SVG: make a gradient to fill the whole shape for every angle given

Tags: javascript, vector, svg, trigonometry, linear-gradients

[image: Trigonometry problem]

Given an angle between 0° and 90°, generate a SVG gradient that fills entire rectangle.

SVG gradients accept two control points rather than angle. Here is the code of the first square on the picture above:

`<linearGradient x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0.5">`

The problem is that the gradient doesn’t cover the entire square. I want to extend the gradient just enough to fill the shape entirely so the red triangle would be not visible. Here is an **[interactive demo](http://codepen.io/NV/pen/uaHws)** (tested in Chrome, Firefox and Safari) to give you a better idea.

---

[Solution in JavaScript](http://codepen.io/NV/pen/lfBgp):

```
function angleToVector(angle) {
    var od = Math.sqrt(2);
    var op = Math.cos(Math.abs(Math.PI/4 - angle)) * od;
    var x = op * Math.cos(angle);
    var y = op * Math.sin(angle);
    return {x: x, y: y};
}
```

---

For [angle between -180° and 180°](http://codepen.io/NV/pen/jcnmK):

```
function angleToPoints(angle) {
    var segment = Math.floor(angle / Math.PI * 2) + 2;
    var diagonal = (1/2 * segment + 1/4) * Math.PI;
    var op = Math.cos(Math.abs(diagonal - angle)) * Math.sqrt(2);
    var x = op * Math.cos(angle);
    var y = op * Math.sin(angle);

    return {
        x1: x < 0 ? 1 : 0,
        y1: y < 0 ? 1 : 0,
        x2: x >= 0 ? x : x + 1,
        y2: y >= 0 ? y : y + 1
    };
}
```

There might be a simpler solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your question as I understand it is this: given a rectangle (whose top left corner is the origin `O = (0, 0)` and whose bottom right corner is `D = (w, h)`) and a line `l` through point `O` at angle `a` (with `0° <= a <= 90°`), find the point `P = (x2, y2)` on `l` such that line `DP` makes a right angle with `l`.

If you draw the diagonal of the rectangle, `OD`, it completes a right triangle with the right angle at `P`. The angle of that diagonal is `atan(h/w)`, and if you take the absolute difference of that from `a` (i.e. `|atan(h/w) - a|`), you'll get the angle in that right triangle at point `O`. Then you can take the cosine of that angle to get the distance between `O` and `P` along `l` as a proportion of the length of `OD` (the hypotenuse). You can multiply out the hypotenuse, and then just multiply that by `cos(a)` and `sin(a)` to get `x2` and `y2`, respectively.

To summarize:

```
|OD| = sqrt(w*w + h*h)
|OP| = cos(|atan(h/w) - a|) * |OD|
x2 = |OP| * cos(a)
y2 = |OP| * sin(a)
```

Comment: `Math.sqrt(2)` seems to do the trick in your code... I guess it's a unit square?